# Logical precedence in Python

Tags: python, syntax, python-2.7, logical-operators

I have a question about python precedence. I have the following code:

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
   ans = min(a,b)
   while ((a%ans is not 0) and (b%ans is not 0)):
       ans -= 1
   return ans
```

My question is about the while logical statement. I added several parenthesis just to make sure that the expression would be evaluated the way I was thinking, but is not. The while loop is being breaked before the both expressions are true. Were I'm wrong?

I found a way to do the same thing without using two expressions, in:

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
   ans = min(a,b)
   while ((a%ans + b%ans is not 0)) :
       ans -= 1
   return ans
```

But I still wanna know why the first code isn't running the way I think it should.

Comment: "The while loop is being breaked before the both expressions are true" maybe you're confused about how while loops work..?

Comment: The while loop will break when *either* condition is `False`.  If you want them both to have to be `False`, use `or`.

Comment: Problem solved. I used and whe i should used for. Thanks to everybody for such a warm welcome in my first question here!

Answer (score 7):

Do not use identity testing (`is` or `is not`) to test for numerical equality. Use `==` or `!=` instead.

```
while a%ans != 0 and b%ans != 0:
```

`is` tests for object identity (that both operators are the same python object), which is not the same thing as testing if the values are *equivalent*.

Since `0` is also considered `False` in a boolean context, you can even omit the `!=` in this case:

```
while a % ans and b % ans:
```

The [`fractions` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd) already has a `gcd()` function that implements the greatest common divisor algorithm correctly:

```
from fractions import gcd

print gcd(a, b)
```

It uses the [Euclidian algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), python style:

```
def gcd(a, b):
    """Calculate the Greatest Common Divisor of a and b.

    Unless b==0, the result will have the same sign as b (so that when
    b is divided by it, the result comes out positive).
    """
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    return a
```